# How do i Get the Values in Excel cells and not the formular Using any Pyhton Package and also how to read from a excel file using the same package

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

[After running the code i'm only getting the formula and not the value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Owoeo.png)

Comment: openpyxl doesn't use Excel at all, so... I guess it does what you want out of the box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you load the workbook, set the flag `data_only` to `True`

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename, data_only=True)
```

Comment: I believe that is possible, but I would recommend researching it before opening a question. It also is beyond the scope of this specific question. Here is an article that goes into writing using openpyxl: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/read-and-write-to-an-excel-file-using-python-openpyxl-module

Comment: thanks, You've made things easier for me